# Поместить повторяющиеся элементы списка в подсписки (в функциональном стиле)

Tags: python, функциональное-программирование

Прошу, помогите реализовать данное задание на ЯП Python в функциональном стиле. Возможно использование генератора списка и функций высшего порядка (map, reduce, filter и т.д.).

Пример:

```
(a a a a b c c a a d e e e e) => ((a a a a)(b)(c c)(a a)(d)(e e e e))
```

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: @extrn, спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил таким образом

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(['a','a','a','b','c','c','a','a','d','e','e','e'])]
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c'], ['a', 'a'], ['d'], ['e', 'e', 'e']]
```